# i am getting an error as " failed: AttributeError: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute 'get_token"

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, toolkit, chaos

While Running Chaos Toolkit Azure related Playbooks , i am getting an error as "  failed: AttributeError: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute 'get_token" though i have passed in the correct Secret ID , Tenant ID , Client ID , SUbscription ID and Client Secret ID.. Even the Subscription has full permission to Service Principal.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls get_token()?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** It would have helped to check the exact code you're trying to run, but from the mentioned error, it looks like you're trying to use the newer libraries in the older ways. When using newer SDK libraries based on `azure.core`, use the `ClientSecretCredential` object from the `azure.identity` library. When using older SDK libraries, use `ServicePrincipalCredentials` from the `azure.common` library.

**Long answer:**
The Azure libraries for Python are currently being updated to share common cloud patterns such as authentication protocols, logging, tracing, transport protocols, buffered responses, and retries.

In the newer version, the authentication mechanism has been re-designed and replaced by `azure-identity` library in order to provide unified authentication based on Azure Identity for all Azure SDKs. Run `pip install azure-identity` to get the package.

So instead of using the `ServicePrincipalCredentials` class from the `azure.common` library, switch to using `ClientSecretCredential` as follows:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id='xxxxx',
    client_id='xxxxx',
    client_secret='xxxxx'
)
```

Here is another related thread with a detailed solution: [Azure Python SDK: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute 'get_token'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64063850/10805761)

Additional references:

- [Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) on GitHub
- [Authenticate with token credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=cmd#authenticate-with-token-credentials)