# Unable to perform Azure ARM deployment because of 'ClientSecretCredential' issues

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-authentication, azure-sdk-python

I want to perform an Azure ARM template deployment using Python. I am using 'ClientSecretCredential' library to construct my Azure credentials. I am using the 'ClientSecretCredential', because according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063850/azure-python-sdk-serviceprincipalcredentials-object-has-no-attribute-get-tok), looks like the way we construct the credentials has beeen enchanced from `azure.common (ServicePrincipalCredentials)` to `azure-identity (ClientSecretCredential)` While performing the deployment, I am getting the error:

```
    Message='ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'
  Source=C:\Users\manjug\Desktop\SQLServer_armtemplate\testFunction.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\manjug\Desktop\SQLServer_armtemplate\testFunction.py", line 109, in executeArmDeployment
    Deployment(properties=deployment_properties)
  File "C:\Users\manjug\Desktop\SQLServer_armtemplate\testFunction.py", line 119, in <module> (Current frame)
    executeArmDeployment('coe-extollo-apis-dev', resourceManagerClient)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve this by:

1. updating the 'azure-mgmt-resource' module to 16.0.0
2. Changing the 'deployments.create_or_update' functions to 'deployments.begin_create_or_update'